# Cargar rapido video recompensado AdMob y Android Studio?

Tags: android, admob

Ojala me pudieran ayudar a resolver este problema que tengo.
Tengo un proyecto en el que tengo los vídeos premiados por admob. Todo va bien, pero tengo un pequeño inconveniente. 
Cuando inicio la aplicación el video me carga, pero me lleva 20 segundos para cargarlo. Eso es mucho tiempo y quiero que se cargue en unos pocos segundos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se tarda menos? 
Pero lo raro que me ocurre es que cuando termino de ver el video automaticamente he puesto para que se cargue otro, pero éste si se carga muy rápido, en 1 segundo ya está cargado. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se cargue tan rápido como pueda cuando inicio la aplicación?

```
package com.android.proyect;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;

import static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource;
import static android.view.Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON;

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity{


    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-000000000000000/00000000"; //My code

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);

        probarboton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        //Anuncio probar video
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Preload the next video ad.
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
            {
                textView4.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"you got %d %s!", rewardItem.getAmount(), rewardItem.getType()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        probarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Log.i("probar","video");
                System.out.println("click boton probar video");
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });

        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        AdRequest adRewardRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, adRewardRequest );
    }

}
```

build.gradle proyect

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

build.gradle app

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.snowdream.android:smartimageview:0.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile files('libs/UnityAdsAdapter.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

Veo que tienes en tu codigo:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Pero en realidad usas `RewardedVideoAd` lo cual es correcto:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAdListener;
```

Me parece que necesitas inicializar los anuncios al cargar tu aplicación

```
 // Inicializar el SDK.
    MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);
 //Anuncio probar video
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
 ...
 ...
```

Te recomiendo revisar la implementación de este ejemplo:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/admob/RewardedVideoExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/ads/rewardedvideoexample/MainActivity.java

el metodo `loadRewardedVideoAd()` :

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

y el metodo `showRewardedVideo` que cargarias al dar click en el boton:

```
private void showRewardedVideo() {
    mShowVideoButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
    }
}


  probarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Log.i("probar","video");
                showRewardedVideo();
                /*System.out.println("click boton probar video");
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }*/
            }
        });
```

Comment: Lo tengo implementado tal y como lo has puesto, es mas lo copie todo de ese tutorial jajajaaj pero me sigue tardando mucho en cargar en anuncio, otras aplicaciones le tardan poquísimo de 2 a 4 segundos y a mi 20 segundos en cargarlo